# Lists supported instruction set in GAS?

Tags: gcc, gnu-assembler

I cross compiled binutils to arm-non-eabi, but GAS from this build complains `-march=armv4t` is invalid option. Is there an option to lists all the supported instruction set for given GAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gas will display target options with `as --target-help`